# Hand Tracking and finger distance Module: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, index-error, mediapipe, cvzone

I'm again trying to solve the problems with my hand tracking module, I fixed some major issues but now when I ran the code it crashes as soon as I show my hand giving this error`INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU. Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\filip\OneDrive\Desktop\pyton\Regolamento Volume\HandTrackingModule.py", line 112, in <module>  main() File "c:\Users\filip\OneDrive\Desktop\pyton\Regolamento Volume\HandTrackingModule.py", line 98, in main       print(lmList[4], lmList[8]) ~~~~~~^^^ IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Once again I'm using Python, OpenCV and Mediapipe and this is the program

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time
import math


class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=1, modelComplexity=1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.modelComplex = modelComplexity
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon

        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.modelComplex, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img

    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):
        xList = []
        yList = []
        bbox = []
        self.lmList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                xList.append(cx)
                yList.append(cy)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                self.lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 5, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            xmin, xmax = min(xList), max(xList)
            ymin, ymax = min(yList), max(yList)
            bbox = xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax

            if draw:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (bbox[0] - 20, bbox[1] - 20),
            (bbox[2] + 20, bbox[3] + 20), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            
            return self.lmList, bbox
    

    def fingersUp(self):
        fingers = []
        # Thumb
        if self.lmList[self.tipIds[0]][1] > self.lmList[self.tipIds[0] - 1][1]:
            fingers.append(1)
        else:
            fingers.append(0)
        # 4 Fingers
        for id in range(1, 5):
            if self.lmList[self.tipIds[id]][2] < self.lmList[self.tipIds[id] - 2][2]:
                fingers.append(1)
            else:
                fingers.append(0)
        return fingers

    def findDistance(self, p1, p2, img, draw=True):

        x1, y1 = self.lmList[p1][1], self.lmList[p1][2]
        x2, y2 = self.lmList[p2][1], self.lmList[p2][2]
        cx, cy = (x1 + x2) // 2, (y1 + y2) // 2
        
        if draw:
            cv2.circle(img, (x1, y1), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.circle(img, (x2, y2), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 255), 3)
            cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        
        length = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
        return length, img, [x1, y1, x2, y2, cx, cy]

def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmList = detector.findPosition(img)  # Modified to capture bbox as well
        if lmList is not None:  # Corrected condition
            print(lmList[4], lmList[8])

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
                (255, 0, 255), 3)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If someone could help me I would be really glad, thank you

I tryed to avoid the problem but the fact is that I need those valutes and It crashes every time I try. I would really appreciate if someone could show me the correction on the code

Comment: did you get this code from "cvzone"/Murtaza?

Comment: Yes but it doesn’t work

Comment: oh great! then you can talk to Murtaza directly. he'll be happy to support you in getting his code to run!

Comment: Where can I ask him?

Comment: where did you find the code? if I were in your place, I'd look there first.

Comment: Computer Vision send me on a YouTube video where I found various Social account but nothing where I can write him

Comment: at the bottom of this page is his email address https://www.murtazahassan.com/ and there's always the youtube comment section, if you found this code in one of his videos